# After 'cordova prepare' xCode constantly fails to install app on my phone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic-framework

I have an issue that constantly pops up since I have upgraded my Mac OSX to **Catalina** and XCode to 11+. I am using `Ionic 1` and whenever I do `sudo cordova prepare` (I know it's not good, but I have to do sudo, otherwise rights issue) I am getting the 'Unable to install your app' error.

Below you can find the logs:

Details

```
Unable to install "YourApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620394
--
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620394
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008016)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d4a581a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d4e6f70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010408f155 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d4e6ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011d35de91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001041c27f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001041c4436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff71df76c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff71df8658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff71dfdc44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff71dfe5d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff71e07c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff72052a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff72051b77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287)
Xcode 11.4.1 (16137)
```

The workaround for this is to change the `bundle identifier` in XCode constantly after every deploy, but this is just not sustainable. Any idea why this is happening and how I can prevent this? Before the XCode and Mac OSX version, I did not have this problem btw.

Comment: The error as written seems to be related to signing issue, maybe the account is identified to your previous version of mac and thus is unvalid account dor new mac, check if you account is available for new version in you account console in apple or maybe it needs kind of validation for new mac version..

Comment: How to validate in that case? How do we do that in the first place?